# Can't upload video over 5GB on App Engine

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, file-upload

I recently decided to move my software hosting to Google App Engine (since we believe it's serverless), but, I am coming across a problem where I cannot upload large video files. This is a big problem, since the point of the software is handling video files.

HTML:

```html
<center>
<form method="POST" action='/tutorial' class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="dropper" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
</form>
</center>

<script type="application/javascript">
Dropzone.options.dropper = {
    paramName: 'file',
    chunking: true,
    maxFiles: 1,
    dictDefaultMessage: "Upload Video",
    acceptedFiles: ".mp4",
    forceChunking: true,
    url: '/tutorial',
    maxFilesize: 10240, // megabytes
    chunkSize: 20000000, // bytes
    retryChunks: true,
    retryChunksLimit: 3,
    autoQueue: false,
    ...
</script>
```

Python:

```py
@app.route('/tutorial', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tutorial():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('tutorial.html', static_folder='static')
    f = request.files['file']
    session['filename'] = secure_filename(f.filename)
    gcs_client = storage.Client()
    storage_bucket = gcs_client.get_bucket('myfiles')
    tmp_file_path = '/tmp/' + session['filename']
    fsr = f.stream.read()
    with open(tmp_file_path, "ab") as out_file:
        out_file.seek(int(request.form["dzchunkbyteoffset"]))
        out_file.write(fsr)
    if int(request.form['dzchunkindex']) + 1 == int(request.form['dztotalchunkcount']):
        blob = storage_bucket.blob(session['filename'])
        blob.upload_from_filename(tmp_file_path, client=gcs_client, timeout=5000)        
        return redirect("/video")
    else:
        return make_response(("Chunk upload successful", 200))
    return redirect("/video")
```

`app.yaml`:

```yaml
runtime: python

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
  
runtime_config:
    operating_system: ubuntu22
    runtime_version: "3.11"

resources:
  cpu: 8
  memory_gb: 32
  disk_size_gb: 20

env: flex
```

I already have way more than enough CPU and RAM required to process this upload, I am not sure why the workers just keep timing out and exiting.

Error:

```
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:51)
[INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 51)
[INFO] Booting worker with pid: 209
```

Comment: Does it work for smaller-sized files?

Comment: @NoCommandLine Yes, but my software generally should accept video 5 ~ 10 GB.

Comment: Can you try removing the ```timeout``` or increasing it?

Comment: @NoCommandLine How would I be able to remove the timeout?

Comment: ```blob.upload_from_filename(tmp_file_path, client=gcs_client, timeout=5000) ```  timeout is an optional parameter - see [docs](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/main/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L2718)